# How can I get my Acer Aspire One to boot up normally?

Tags: lightdm

Is there any way of making my Netbook(Acer Aspire One ZA3) with Ubuntu 12.04, start  up easier, at the moment what iu have to do to get to ubuntu is a hastle and im looking to make it easier.

When i turn my Acer Aspire One ZA3 on it loads the Acer logo then goes black.
To get to Ubuntu i am currently pressing ctrl+alt and F3 which takes me to some writing. I am then logging in  and typing " sudo restart lightdm" , putting in my pasword again and it will take me to the Ubuntu screen.

Is there any way of setting this to happen automatically? or at least without as much hastle?

just realised there are updates, so i will do those, and see if it holds answer ;)..... Nope it didnt :(

Comment: That problem may be hardware related. Can you add the output of `lspci` to the question.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by adding the output of lspci , i found what ive been doing on other questions about net books on here, but i dont really understand it

Comment: Have you actually left the black screen to see if anything happens afterwards ? It could still be loading Ubuntu... Failing that try something lighter like Xubuntu as that should work better on a netbook...

Comment: Well, open a terminal window (ctrl-alt-t), type `lspci`, hit 'Enter'. Copy the output and add it to the question. Alternatively, just tell us which graphics is there. I suspect you have a machine with Intel's infamous GMA500, just want to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

After you press <kbd>ctrl+alt+F3</kbd> (or any of F1 through F6), just press <kbd>ctrl+alt+F7</kbd> to get back to Xwindows. There is known bugs with the video chipset used in this model.